# Cron and php issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

The content of cron.php is :

```
<?php
    $to = "my email";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "Hello world!";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Im using codeigniter, but I don't believe that this framework somehow can influence my file.
In the image you can see where is located my file (cron.php)
[image]

In the cpanel->cronjobs , at the **Command** i tried this version:

1. ls -la /domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php
2. /domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php
3. php /domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php

etc, but none of them is working. Im getting this error: **Could not open input file: /domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php**

I tried also this version:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php
```

and this one :

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http:/www.ebis-servicii.ro/cron.php
```

Can anyone help me with this ?
maybe im doing smth wrong in the cpanel:
this is how my cron is set: 
[image]

Comment: anyone , who can help me with this ? :)

Comment: what is ur file permision ?

Comment: my cron.php file permission is 644

Comment: change it to 755 nd check,

u dont hav execute permision to user

Comment: i tried with 777, but still nothing

Comment: check my post again, i posted an image

Comment: are u sure ur php is in 
/usr/local/bin/php ?? 

normaly its path is /usr/bin/php

Comment: Are you sure about your php code file? Usually, in Cpanel environment the full path to a file should be `/home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php` And I am sure that you are missing this `home/username` in your path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following command ?

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php
```

*** Also, can you make sure that the file path `/home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php` is correct.

**HERE IS THE ADDITIONAL INFO :**

Command to run a PHP5 cron job:
`php /home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php`

Optional flag sometimes required for a PHP cron job:
`php -q /home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php`

Command to run a PHP4 cron job:
`/usr/local/php4/bin/php /home/ebisserv/domains/ebis-servicii.ro/public_html/cron.php`